# Forms in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I'm new in Zend Framework, and I'm having a problem.
usually when verifying data in forms we use javascript like bellow:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function verify(){
            if( document.form.name.value=="") { alert("Error");  return false}
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form onSubmit="verify()" name="form">
        <input name="name" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using zend forms and i don't have a clue how to do it.

```
<?php

class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form {

    public function init() {
        $login = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('login');

        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('password');

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel("Login");

        $remember = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('remember');


        $this->addElements(array($login, $password,$remember ,$submit));
    }

}
?>
```

Any help please.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it the same way as before, but here is how to tell `Zend_Form` to add the `onsubmit` event to your so that the HTML code generated contains the attribute in the `<form>` tag.

```
class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form {

    public function init() {
        $this->setAttrib('onsubmit', 'return verify()');

        // rest of your form code to add elements
    }
}
```

This adds an attribute `onsubmit` to the `Zend_Form` object, such that when the form is rendered your `<form>` tag has `onsubmit="return verify()"` in it.

Now you can just put the actual Javascript code to verify the form in the view script itself, or an external javascript file that you can reference in a `<script>` tag.